# How to create classify_image_graph_def.pb from my model?

Tags: tensorflow

I used [this repo](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow) in order to convert my caffe model into tensorflow. I ended with 2 files : one is python class and the second is npy file with the model weights.

However i want to generate a single file, with the same format as this [one](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz) (this file, named classify_image_graph_def.pb, can be used to forward the net over any test image).

I'm interested in this format specifically because this is the one required by the script [quantize_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantization/tools/quantize_graph.py).

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to convert all variables in the graph into constant. This could be done using the [freeze_graph tool](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py).
But since this tool is not part of the runtime tensorflow library o found it more convenient to do it with the following lines (without having to build freeze_graph):

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

### create some graph here ###
##############################

graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def()
output_node_names = "output0,output1" # put the names of the output nodes here

# freeze all parameters and save
output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess, graph_def, output_node_names.split(","))
with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph_file, "wb") as f:
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```